# Comparing to previous string gets me stuck in a loop

Tags: c#, wpf, downloadstring

Ok, so I have a program that checks a twitch url for whenever someone new follows the channel by comparing a certain string is different from a "temp" string that I use for reference. But instead of only outputting a message every time the string is different it gets stuck in a loop of outputting the latest follower and then second latest follower then latest follower again etc.

What am I missing? Also, is there a better way of checking if a certain string is updated?

```
        private void DonationListen()
    {
        try
        {
            followers = this.donationClient.DownloadString("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/" + channel.Trim() + "/follows");

            donationTimer.Interval = 10000;
            donationTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CheckUpdates);
            donationTimer.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void CheckUpdates(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        donationTimer.Stop();

        int startIndex = followers.IndexOf("display_name\":") + 15;
        int endIndex = followers.IndexOf(",\"logo", startIndex);
        prevFollower = followers.Substring(startIndex, (endIndex - 1) - startIndex);

        if (firstRun == true)
        {
            temp = prevFollower;
        }
        else if (prevFollower != temp)
        {
            //New follower detected
            temp = prevFollower;
            if (updateFollower != null)
            {
                updateFollower(prevFollower);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Follower is the same as before
        }

        firstRun = false;
        DonationListen();
    }
```

I'm thinking it might have something to do with the downloadstring trying to get a new string from the url but failing since it's currently being updated and therefore the CheckUpdates doesn't have correct information or something?

Comment: Does this code demonstrate the actual issue? I don't see any loop or strings being output.

Comment: There's no loop other than the timer loop and the output is the updateFollower(prevFollower); line.

Comment: Why do I keep getting downvoted for asking normal questions on this site? Then I can't post another question for like 5 days... real user friendly.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be worth a read... Instead of code-dumping, try to reproduce the error in a new, minimal example.  I often find that if I do this when getting ready to post a question, I end up finding my own silly mistakes, and don't even need to post a question anymore.

Comment: @Adkit Didn't downvote either, but your question is a little vague/broad -- it lacks specific details about the problem and contextual clues about what code you're showing us and how exactly it relates to the problem. I know it's frustrating, but if you really take the time to ask as clear of a question as possible, you'll start seeing positive votes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good code example, it is difficult to know for sure what the problem is. So we are left inspecting the code you did show us.

Based on that, it appears to me as though your "loop" is being caused by repeatedly subscribing to the same event.

In your `DonationListen()` method, you have this statement:

```
donationTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(CheckUpdates);
```

In the `CheckUpdates()` method (i.e. the handler you are subscribing), you have this statement (as the very last statement):

```
DonationListen();
```

In other words, every time the timer's `Elapsed` event is raised, you add another event handler instance to the event. For every handler you add, the `CheckUpdates()` method will be called.

Again, without a good code example, it is difficult to know for sure what the best fix would be. But given the code that is here, it appears to me that you could just remove that last statement from the `CheckUpdates()` method, as the `DonationListen()` method does not appear to do anything that needs doing again.

Comment: Exactly. put the Interval to a smaller time and you see how fast you'll get a stackoverflow Exception. The timer is almost like a thread and you are recursivly creating new threads. Since the period is 1 sec, after 30 sec you will be having 1.049.600 threads. This will kill any computer in a minute